# How to use SUM function to get no of totalno of duplicate records from from SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have several tables and I just want to check if duplicates are found with some conditions in those tables.

Here is my SQL script:

```
--SELECT SUM(intSubCount) //this is first line that gets total no of summary
--Check Duplicate Subscribers Found :
(SELECT
     s.Id, s.EmailAddress,
     (SELECT Name FROM tbl_User_master 
      WHERE Id = s.user_id) AS CreatedBy,
     s.SubscriptionDateTime, d.intSubCount
 FROM 
     (SELECT EmailAddress, COUNT(*) as intSubCount
      FROM tbl_Subscribers 
      WHERE user_id = '1' AND category_id = '17'
      GROUP BY EmailAddress
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS d
 INNER JOIN 
     tbl_Subscribers s ON s.EmailAddress = d.EmailAddress)

--Check Duplicate From Users Found :
(SELECT
     f.Id, f.Name, f.EmailAddress,
     (SELECT Name FROM tbl_User_master WHERE Id = f.user_id) AS CreatedBy,
     f.CreatedDate, d.intFromCount
 FROM 
     (SELECT EmailAddress, COUNT(*) AS intFromCount
      FROM tbl_From_master 
      WHERE user_id = '1'
      GROUP BY EmailAddress
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS d
 INNER JOIN 
     tbl_From_master f ON f.EmailAddress = d.EmailAddress)

--Check Duplicate  Categories Found
(SELECT
    c.Id,c.CategoryName,(SELECT Name FROM tbl_User_master WHERE Id = c.user_id) As CreatedBy, d.intCatCount
FROM (
     SELECT CategoryName, COUNT(*) as intCatCount
     FROM tbl_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
     GROUP BY CategoryName
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS d
INNER JOIN tbl_Categories c ON c.CategoryName = d.CategoryName)

--Check Duplicate  Templates Categories Found
(SELECT
    t.Id,t.CategoryName,(SELECT Name FROM tbl_User_master WHERE Id = t.user_id) As CreatedBy, d.intTCatCount
FROM (
     SELECT CategoryName, COUNT(*) as intTcatCount
     FROM tbl_Template_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
     GROUP BY CategoryName
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS d
INNER JOIN tbl_Template_Categories t ON t.CategoryName = d.CategoryName)

--Check Duplicate Templates Found
(SELECT
    t.Id,t.TemplateName,(SELECT Name FROM tbl_User_master WHERE Id = t.user_id) As CreatedBy,t.Created_date, d.intTCount
FROM (
     SELECT TemplateName, COUNT(*) as intTCount
     FROM tbl_Template_master WHERE user_id='1'
     GROUP BY TemplateName
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS d
INNER JOIN tbl_Template_master t ON t.TemplateName = d.TemplateName)
```

now I just got count to int variable to every query now I just want to SUM (intSubCount,intFromCount,intCatCount,intTCatCount,intTCount) see my first line of this script

for running this script i got this results:

```
(4 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)
```

How can I achieve this? Please help me out guys..

**------------------------------edited--------------------------**

i tried out this sol but gives wrong no of rows

```
SELECT SUM(intSubCount) as GrandTotal
FROM(
    --Check Duplicate Subscribers Found :
    SELECT COUNT(*) as intSubCount
    FROM tbl_Subscribers WHERE user_id='1' AND category_id='17'
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    UNION ALL

    --Check Duplicate From Users Found :
    SELECT COUNT(*) as  intFromCount
    FROM tbl_From_master WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    UNION ALL

    --Check Duplicate  Categories Found
    SELECT COUNT(*) as  intCatCount
    FROM tbl_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY CategoryName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    UNION ALL

    --Check Duplicate Templates Categories Found
    SELECT COUNT(*) as  intTCatCount
    FROM tbl_Template_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY CategoryName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    UNION ALL

    --Check  Templates Categories Found
    SELECT COUNT(*) as  intTCount
    FROM tbl_Template_master WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY TemplateName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    --UNION ALL
    ) AS Totals
```

result is :

```
Grand Total :
7
```

Comment: `UNIOIN` all your queries and `SUM` your counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is the `sum` of each individual query and each individual query will only ever return the one value, you can simply add them up as sub-selects:

```
select (select Query 1 total) + (select Query 2 total) + (select Query 3 total) as GrandTotal
```

another option is to `union` the results and `sum` over the resulting dataset:

```
select sum(total) as GrandTotal
from(select total
     from Query 1

     union all    -- the 'all' ensures no duplicate numbers are removed for an accurate total

     select total
     from Query 2

     union all

     select total
     from Query 3
    ) as totals
```

---

## Edit for clarity

Either:

```
SELECT 
    --Check Duplicate Subscribers Found :
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as intSubCount
     FROM tbl_Subscribers WHERE user_id='1' AND category_id='17'
     GROUP BY EmailAddress
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    +
    --Check Duplicate From Users Found :
    (SELECT intFromCount
     FROM tbl_From_master WHERE user_id='1'
     GROUP BY EmailAddress
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    +
    --Check Duplicate  Categories Found
    (SELECT intCatCount
     FROM tbl_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
     GROUP BY CategoryName
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
as GrandTotal
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(intSubCount) as GrandTotal
FROM(
    --Check Duplicate Subscribers Found :
    SELECT COUNT(*) as intSubCount
    FROM tbl_Subscribers WHERE user_id='1' AND category_id='17'
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

    UNION ALL

    --Check Duplicate From Users Found :
    SELECT intFromCount
    FROM tbl_From_master WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    
    UNION ALL

    --Check Duplicate  Categories Found
    SELECT intCatCount
    FROM tbl_Categories WHERE user_id='1'
    GROUP BY CategoryName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS Totals
```

Comment: can I use your code as it is you posted out or I have modified Query 1 total with other text please clear to me..

Comment: @shalingajjar  You would need to put your actual `select` statements in place of my dummy values

Comment: @shalingajjar  See my edit.  Though you really could have just tried this yourself...

Comment: I just want to sum all variable like intSubCount,intCatCunt… vice versa

Comment: @shalingajjar  That is exactly what my answer does.  Please actually try something and see if it works for you

Comment: ya i tried out but it's gives me 7 well result is 8. see my edit